# Creating a crc8 function with lua

Tags: lua, crc, crc8

Is there a simple algorithm to create a crc8 checksum from a table in lua?
Polynomial should be x^8+x^5+x^4+1 (0x31)
This algorithm will be used to check the UID of the DS28CM00 UID-chip.
Here you can find a table returned by the chip (LS-byte last) :

```
table = {112,232,9,80,1,0,0}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: this is not a coding service. the internet is full of crc 8 implementations in various languages and pseudo code. why do you expect us to do your work? he help to solve problems, we don't solve them. btw you shouldn't use `table` as a variable name. `table` interfaces Lua's table library. there are plenty implementations

Comment: You should give an example of CRC returned by the chip (the 8-th byte of the table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Lua 5.3+

```
local function crc8(t)
   local c = 0
   for _, b in ipairs(t) do
      for i = 0, 7 do
         c = c >> 1 ~ ((c ~ b >> i) & 1) * 0x8C
      end
   end
   return c
end

print(crc8{112, 232, 9, 80, 1, 0, 0})  --> 219
print(crc8{2, 0x1C, 0xB8, 1, 0, 0, 0}) --> 0xA2 as in example from AN-27
```

---

For Lua 5.2-

```
local function crc8(t)
   local c = 0
   for _, b in ipairs(t) do
      for i = 0, 7 do
         local c0 = c % 2
         local b0 = b % 2
         c = (c - c0) / 2
         b = (b - b0) / 2
         if c0 + b0 == 1 then
            c = c + 0x80 + (c % 16 < 8 and 8 or -8) + (c % 8 < 4 and 4 or -4)
         end
      end
   end
   return c
end
```

Comment: Could you explain your code in detail? I would need the same function for another polynom. (0x107)

Comment: @DanielK - `0x31` is just the reverse bits of `0x8C`.  This way you can modify the code to work with another polynom

Comment: thanks for the hint but unfortunately the code is not working for my application. I am communicating with a sensor via I2C which adds a PEC at the end. According to the data {0x00,0x07,0x01,0x12,0x3b} the sensor says that the PEC is 0xD5. But with your code I can not get the same result. (I used 0xE0 instead of 0x8C because my polynom is (0x107). I found a [website](http://www.ghsi.de/pages/subpages/Online%20CRC%20Calculation/index.php?Polynom=100000111&Message=000701123b) which calculates it correctly but I don't know why your code doesn't fit. I will create a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725593/pec-calculation-in-lua