# PEC calculation in Lua

Tags: lua, i2c, crc8

I am struggling to calculate the packet error code (PEC) of received data over I2C in order to know check if the data is valid.
[PEC Definition](http://www.smbus.org/specs/)

I used the code stated in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280849/creating-a-crc8-function-with-lua/68283266) but it does not work for me.

The data looks like this: 0x00, 0x07, 0x01, 0x12, 0x3b, 0xd5

PEC is 0xd5 which is based on the polynomial = x^8+ x^2+ x^1+ x^0 - 0x107

This works also fine with [this calculator](http://www.ghsi.de/pages/subpages/Online%20CRC%20Calculation/index.php?Polynom=100000111&Message=000701123b).

So my question is, where is the difference between the code from the website and the one from the linked question:

```lua
local function crc8(t)
   local c = 0
   for _, b in ipairs(t) do
      for i = 0, 7 do
         c = c >> 1 ~ ((c ~ b >> i) & 1) * 0xE0
      end
   end
   return c
end
```

Comment: what is not working with the solution? do you get errors? the wrong value? no value?

Comment: I get the wrong values with the shown code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definition of CRC uses reversed bits in all data bytes.

```
local function reverse(x)
   -- reverse bits of a byte
   local y = 0
   for j = 1, 8 do
      y = y * 2 + (x&1)
      x = x >> 1
   end
   return y
end

local function crc8(t)
   local c = 0
   for _, b in ipairs(t) do
      b = reverse(b)
      for i = 0, 7 do
         c = c >> 1 ~ ((c ~ b >> i) & 1) * 0xE0
      end
   end
   c = reverse(c)
   return c
end

print(tohex(crc8{0x00, 0x07, 0x01, 0x12, 0x3b}))  -->   0xd5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works now for my communication. Only one small thing which is not working is the 'tohex' function. I used 'string.format' instead:
print(string.format("%X",(crc8{0x00, 0x07, 0x01, 0x12, 0x3b})))  -->   0xd5

Comment: @DanielK - Yes, `tohex` is my custom function, it is absent in standard Lua.  I should have used string.format instead.